# WP7 - How to have a textbox refuse focus

Tags: focus, windows-phone-7.1

The phonetextbox control in the silverlight toolkit is bugged because tapping on the action item which is inside the textbox causes the textbox to acquire focus and bring up the keyboard. In the handler of the action item the phonetextbox is then returning focus to the root, but that causes the keyboard to appear and then disappear.

On iOS I would simply detect the button press in a will accept focus handler and refuse focus. Does there exist a will accept focus for windows phone controls? Such that you can hit test and return false if you don't want focus.

Or if anyone knows if there is another way to have the keyboard not appear on focus so it won't flicker in and out.

If not I will simply add a button outside of the control to clear its contents, unless anyone has other ideas.  In my iOS app I also have a textbox internal history icon I'd like to implement as well but don't see any such thing in my googling. This is a dictionary search control.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use the [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.isreadonly.aspx) property, and bind it to a bool that checks if focus is accepted or not. This only limits how the GUI treats the control, so you can still set text programmatically for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You Just use the this.Focus(); to close the SIP(Soft Input Panel). It will remove the focus from Keyboard and set it to page. It is working for me.

happy coding.

Thanks